# Why is my prototype method returning undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have created a prototype method that return true and false. The problem is that it doesn't return the value. I know it reaches the statement because I have used console.log() when the condition is met but doesn't return the value.

I cant seem to figure this out. If anyone can help me out here I would really appreciate it. Below is my code

```
function Validation(){
    this.checkRequired = function(){
        $(".modifiers-group-cont").each(function(){
            var select_opt_notify = $(this).find(".select-option-notify");

            /*The radio buttons that are required  are always going to be marked check,thats why we are only
            * checking for the checkbox*/
            if($(this).attr("data-is-checked") == "false" && $(this).attr("data-input-type") == "checkbox"){
              select_opt_notify.show();
                return  false;
            } else {
                select_opt_notify.hide();
                return "true";
            }
        });
    }

function ModifierPost(){
    (function(){
        $("#add-to-cart").click(function(){
            console.log(validation.constructor); //Shows undefined

            if(validation.checkRequired()){
            $.post("#",$("form").serialize()+ "&item_id=" + item_id);
            }
        });
    })();
}
```

Comment: Where's the prototype method? `this.methodName` is not the same as a prototype method.

Comment: "I have created a prototype method" no, you've just declared a method on an object. A prototype method would have a declaration along the lines of `Validation.prototype.checkRequired = function () {...}`.

Comment: @zzzzBov Okay sorry I got confused between a prototype and a regular method in an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statements belong to the function in `each`:

```
$(".modifiers-group-cont").each(function(){
```

You'll need to expose the values you'd like to return to the outer scope and call `return` *after* the call to `each`.

Answer (score 0):

You have created your function with Capital V and calling with Smaill v in the validation function name
That is the reason it is giving you undefined the place you have mentioned in your code.

```
 console.log(validation.constructor); //Shows undefined
 if(validation.checkRequired()){
```

it should be with Capital V like

```
console.log(Validation.constructor); //Shows undefined
if(Validation.checkRequired()){
```